# Substring substitution in bash

Tags: string, bash, replace, str-replace, tr

my problem of today is to replace in a string like this --> `6427//6422 6429//6423 6428//6421`

every `//` with a `,`. I tried with different commands:

- `finalString=${startingString//[//]/,}` doesn't work
- `fileTemp=$(echo -e "$line\n" | tr "//" ","` does a double substitution like this:

  `hello//world` ---> `hello,,world`

Someone has an idea of a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BASH string manipulations (need to escape `/` with `\/`):

```
s='6427//6422 6429//6423 6428//6421'
echo "${s//\/\//,}"
6427,6422 6429,6423 6428,6421
```

Similarly using awk:

```
awk -F '//' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' <<< "$s"
6427,6422 6429,6423 6428,6421
```

**PS:** `tr` cannot be used here since `tr` translates **each character** in input to another character in the output and here you're dealing with 2 characters `//`.

Comment: Or without backslashes: `o=${s%%//*};while [[ $s != ${str#*//} ]] ;do o+=,${s%%//*}; s=${s#*//};done;o+="$s"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed as

```
$ echo "6427//6422 6429//6423 6428//6421" | sed 's#//#,#g'
6427,6422 6429,6423 6428,6421
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the sed command like this

```
sed 's#/\{2,2\}#,#g'
```

finds double "/" and replace with ","

Example

```
echo "6427//6422 6429//6423 6428//6421"| sed 's#/\{2,2\}#,#g'
```

Results

```
6427,6422 6429,6423 6428,6421
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`tr`](https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html):

```
echo "6427//6422 6429//6423 6428//6421" | tr -s '/' ','
6427,6422 6429,6423 6428,6421
```

Note the addition of the `-s` flag, an alias for `--squeeze-repeats`:

> Replace each input sequence of a repeated character that is listed in
> SET1 with a single
> occurrence of that character.